# Go to specific step?

Tags: jquery-steps

I want to use the plugin jquery-steps with the enablePagination property set to false (without "previous" and "next" button). How can I go to the next step ?
What function should I call ?

Comment: https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki/Methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I got the answer :
$("#wizard").steps("next");